# Iterating an array of objects using for of loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object `x` with a bunch of properties. One of the properties is `heroes` which has the value of array of objects. I am interested in iterating through the array of objects of `heroes` and accessing specific properties from it.

Here is the code:

```
x = {id: "prim1", description: "planner", heroes: [{name: "arrow", universe: "dc"}, {name: "shields", universe: "marvel"}]};
```

I have written a simple `for loop` to achieve what I wanted as follows:

```
for (let idx = 0; idx < x.heroes.length; idx++) {
   console.log(x.heroes[idx].universe);
}
```

How can I implement the same using the latest ES6's `for of` loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array You have several options to iterate depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution using [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop , you just need to to call the iterable element using this structure:

```
for (variable of iterable) {
  console.log(variable)
}
```

On each iteration you can get the current variable.

```js
x = {
  id: "prim1",
  description: "planner",
  heroes: [{
    name: "arrow",
    universe: "dc"
  }, {
    name: "shields",
    universe: "marvel"
  }]
};

for (let idx = 0; idx < x.heroes.length; idx++) {
  console.log(x.heroes[idx].universe);
}

for (let o of x.heroes) {
  console.log(o.universe);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Neji :) I wasn't invoking `o.universe`, instead I was calling `x.heroes[o]` which was of course returning `undefined`. A dumb mistake. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like with [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
 var x = {id: "prim1", description: "planner", heroes: [{name: "arrow",  universe: "dc"}, {name: "shields", universe: "marvel"}]};
  
   for (let item of x.heroes) {

     console.log(item.universe); 

   }
```

Comment: the question is how to impement the same loop using the latest ES6's `for loop`

Comment: @Neji , yes I just miss the word ES6's **for of** loop